# Combine all dataframe columns into one column as a JSON with JSON types preserved

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, """{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}"""),
  (64, """{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}""")
).toDF("number", "word")
```

`someDF.show(false)` :

```
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|number|word                                                           |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|8     |{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}              |
|64    |{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}              |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Problem statement:**
I want to combine all columns into 1 column with JSON types preserved inside the single output column. That is no escaping of quotes etc. like I got below.

**What I tried:**

`someDF.toJSON.toDF.show(false)`

```
// this escaped the quotes, which I don't want
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"number":8,"word":"{\"details\":{\"decision\":\"ACCEPT\",\"source\":\"Rules\"}"}               |
|{"number":64,"word":"{\"details\":{\"decision\":\"ACCEPT\",\"source\":\"Rules\"}"}              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Same issue with `someDF.select( to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("value"))`

What I want:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"number":8,"word":{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}}                          |
|{"number":64,"word":{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}}                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:**
Though I used a simple dataframe here, in reality I have hundreds of columns so manually defined schema doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The "word" column in "someDF" is string type, so `to_json` treats it as a regular string. The key here is to convert the "word" column to a struct type before using `to_json`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val someDF = Seq(
  (8, """{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}"""),
  (64, """{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}""")
).toDF("number", "word")

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("details", StructType(Seq(StructField("decision", StringType), StructField("source", StringType))))))
someDF.select(to_json(struct($"number", from_json($"word", schema).alias("word"))).alias("value")).show(false)
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"number":8,"word":{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}} |
|{"number":64,"word":{"details":{"decision":"ACCEPT","source":"Rules"}}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @memoryz, this works, but in reality instead of `someDF` used here, I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns, most of the columns being a JSON field. Is there a way to combine all these columns into a single column without specifying columns/schema manually? Can the schema be generated from the dataframe and used?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the list of columns using `columns` method on your dataframe and then build manually your JSON string using combination of `concat` and `concat_ws` built-in functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat, concat_ws, lit}

val result = someDF.select(
  concat(
    lit("{"),
    concat_ws(
      ",", 
      someDF.columns.map(x => concat(lit("\""), lit(x), lit("\":"), col(x))): _*
    ),
    lit("}")).as("value")
)
```